# Installing XAMPP

Tags: 64-bit, files, executable, chmod, xampp

I'm new to linux and I'm trying to install XAMPP 
I downloaded the file and I cant execute it, I followed the Instruction on http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#374
but when I'm trying the command

```
chmod 755 chmod 755 xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run
```

it's showing

```
cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-0-installer.run’: No such file or directory
```

I'm using 64bit ubuntu 13.04 
please help me

Comment: please install the native LAMP stack. Less hassle, less problems,  more secure. (It is as easy as `sudo apt-get install tasksel` then `tasksel` and choose LAMP and you have a working apache, mysql, php).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following (Note the version of xampp!)

1. Navigate to the location where the file is currently located using cd command, usually the Downloads folder

   ```
   cd Downloads/
   ```
2. Then run the commands

   ```
   sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run
   sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run
   ```

This will install xampp under `/opt` folder

3. To start xampp services,

   ```
   sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It means that it doesn't find the file you downloaded.

Did you entered in the directory where the file is saved?
Something like:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, But please can you write the full command for me, I'm still learning and I don't know how to use `cd`

Comment: `cd` stands for change directory. Thus if you downloaded the file in the standard directory Downloads, once you open the terminal you move to that directory with exactly the command I wrote in the answer: `cd ~/Downloads`.

Comment: You may also want to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal to have some more informations about the terminal